# Best way to update a list of entities with QueryDsl, JPA and EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, querydsl

Working with QueryDsl and JPA, EclipseLink, I need to update the same column for a list of entities and store that modifications in the database, **Is there a difference (terme of performance) between :**

1 -Doing that by getting all the ids and execute a single query that update all the rows at the same time.

2 -Using the entityManager to merge the updated entities one by one.

**1.**

```
 public void updateProcessedForCarList( List<Car> CarList, boolean processed) {

 List<Long> ids = CarList.stream().map(v -> v.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList()):
         getQuery().update(CAR_TABLE).set(CAR_TABLE.processed, processed)
                .where(CAR_TABLE.id.in(ids)).execute();
}
```

---

**2.**

```
  public List<Car> updateProcessedForCarList( List<Car> CarList, boolean processed) {

         CarList.stream().forEach(car -> {
            car.setProcessed(processed);
            getEntityManager().merge(car);
        });

        return vsCmdbUpdateInfoBEList;
    }
```

Comment: Some JPA providers, if configured, can write out the multiple update statements for each 'car' update into one batch statement for your DB to handle, bringing the performance to be (more) inline with a single query statement. It still has to handle the entity merge behavior, but that can be good as well if there is an underlying cache that you want to have maintained anyway. With the query update approach, you must maintain the state of any cached entities yourself.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the answer, I am using a batch writing size:1000, and when testing both of the mentioned methods i have the best results with the second method (entityManager merge).

Answer (score 0):

It depends:

Option 1 is much faster, but if you have any logic or listeners that should be executed will be bypassed. Also, you cannot proceed with the List of cars because they will not have the same state as the database.